# Why is IV different between put and call of same strike

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, put-call-parity

In his book 'Dynamic Hedging' Nassim Taleb says that the volatility of an OTM put should be exactly equal to that of a corresponding in the money call of same strike.

But in option chains, the calls always have a slightly higher IV than the corresponding put.

Is this because I am looking at American option chains and not European?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does implied vol vary for calls vs puts?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7604/does-implied-vol-vary-for-calls-vs-puts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since American style options allow early exercise, put-call parity will not hold for American options (unless they are held to expiration).

In practice, there is also a difference between calls and puts for European options as well. The full description is here:
[What causes the call and put volatility surface to differ?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/what-causes-the-call-and-put-volatility-surface-to-differ)