# What accounts for the difference between these two option strategies?

Tags: option-pricing

Same underlying, same strike, same expiration. One is a covered call, the other is cash secured put.

These are screenshots taken from a website. As you can see, they are similar, but the max win levels are different.

[image]
[image]

The implied vols seem to be different. Is this simply due to the two options having slightly different liquidity?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, Calls and Puts should have the same IV via Put-Call Parity. However, sometimes they do not exactly obey:

- Are the options American? American options do not obey PCP ([Why is IV different between put and call of same strike](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17483/why-is-iv-different-between-put-and-call-of-same-strike))
- Perhaps just due to demand and supply they do not obey PCP. In this case, I see that the prices of the two strats are the same? But via PCP (I guess the current spot price is 136.8):

\begin{equation}
C - P = S_0 - Ke^{-r(T-t)} = 136.8 - 130.0 = 6.8
\end{equation}

Therefore, the call should be above the price of the put by 6.8 to have the same IV. That's just my intuition on your problem, please feel free to correct/clarify/add more details/inquiries.

Comment: It's a single stock option, and those tend to be American IIRC. It means you have potential exercise when there's a dividend. Perhaps that is what is at play?

Comment: Yup, then since American options do not obey PCP, they should not have same IV.